# Backbone: dynamic views hierarchy with templates

Tags: templates, backbone.js, view

I have three different view templates: "post", "comment", "add new comment". The main template is "post". I need to find out how to place "comments" and "add new comment" templates into theyr divs in the "post" template. Or any other methods to make this structure:

```
    - post
        - comments
        - add new post form
    - post
    ...
```

It is similar to facebook wall

Javascript for Backbone:

```
// Post View
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $("#post").html(),
    ...
    render: function () {
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        var thisPost = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(tmpl(thisPost));
    }
});
var postView = new PostView();
postView.render();

// Comments List
var CommentsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#comments', // how to place it to #comments div in "post" template? This line doesn't work
    ...
    addNewCommentForm: function (post_id) {
        var tmpl = _.template($("#addCommentTemplate").html());
        this.$('#addNewComment').append(tmpl()); // How to place it to #addNewComment div in "post" template? This line doesn't work
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<script id="post" type="text/template">
    <%= text %>
    <div id='comments'>...</div>
    <div id='addNewComment'>...</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your code.  The first being that you aren't actually putting the `PostView.el` into the DOM.  Through `PostView.render()`, you are populating `PostView.$el` and subsequently `PostView.el`, but you're not actually putting it into the page (DOM).  Additionally, by setting the `el` on `CommentsListView`, you're not really doing anything there.  If you wanted to set the `el` to an existing element, then you would do something like this: `el: $('#comments')`.  Or if you want to render the `CommentsListView` dynamically and inject it into the DOM, then you would want to just make the element have an id of 'comments' by doing defining the id property like so: `id: 'comments'`.  Those are just the two most obvious problems with the code.  I got a semi-working example running here: http://codepen.io/jayd3e/pen/hAEDv.